# Pagination with tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tire

I am looking to use Tire gem for pagination in Elastic Search in my ruby-script but params[:page] is detected as an undefined local variable:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'tire'
require 'json'
require 'pp'
require 'fileutils'
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'
require 'kaminari'

def SearchTesh

def self.aggregate_cost(account_id, start_date, end_date, options)

  return nil if options[:tax_query] && options[:total_query] # both can't be true
  if options[:tax_query] || options[:total_query] #strip day (keep only month) if either is true
    start_date,end_date = start_date[0...-3], end_date[0...-3]
  end

  query_string = "PayerAccountId:\"#{account_id}\" AND UsageStartDate:[#{start_date} TO #{end_date}]"
  opt = { :page => (params[:page] || 1), :size => 100 }
  search_results = Tire.search '*', opt do
    query { string "#{query_string}" }
    from opt[:size].to_i * (opt[:page].to_i-1)
  end
  return nil if search_results.blank?
  aggregated_results = parse_search_result(
      search_results, {tax_query: options[:tax_query], total_query: options[:total_query]})
  return aggregated_results
 end
end
```

This is my function and at the line:
`opt = { :page => (params[:page] || 1), :size => 100 }`
the following error comes up:

> tasks/test_search.rb:27:in `aggregate_cost': undefined local variable or method`params' for SearchTest:Class (NameError)

Comment: this happens because the `params` hash is only available in your controllers and views. You have to pass it as an argument, probably in your `options` hash ;)

Comment: I don't have any model & view. Its an isolated ruby script.
So how can I access kaminari with tire for pagination without params[:page]?

Comment: from where do you call `self.aggregate_cost`? from that place, you should be able to use the params hash, then call `SearchTest.aggregate_cost(account_id, start_date, end_date, page: params[:page])` and use `option[:page]` instead of `params[:page]`

Comment: Actually params[:page] is the parameter that is passed by kaminari gem. & I am calling `self.aggregate_cost` in via shell script as `rails runner -development tasks/SearchTest.rb`